# How can I flush logging before terminating the actor system?

Tags: logging, akka.net

I'm using Serilog and I notice when shutting down the actor system, not all outstanding log messages have been processed before custom loggers like Serilog are removed. Because of this, a bunch of messages are no longer sent to the Serilog sink and they end up in the default logger instead.

As a workaround, I use this in a `ReceiveAsync` handler:

```cs
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
Context.System.Terminate();
```

I can probably use an `AutoResetEvent` or similar in a non-async handler or an FSM `OnTermination` handler.

The workaround above is just that though, a workaround. Is there a way to flush the logs? Note that I already flush Serilog before shutting down the actor system, that part works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the global `Log` class, call `Log.CloseAndFlush()` before termination.

If you're using an IoC container or similar to manage a `Logger` instance separately, that's not assigned to the global `Log.Logger` property, make sure the container (or your app code) `Dispose()`s the logger instance before termination.

Comment: I can't check now cause I'm not at the office, but that's just Serilog flushing isn't it? I call that already. The problem is Akka is removing all custom loggers during shutdown, before all pending log messages have been passed to the custom logger.

Comment: Ah, I see - thanks for the clarification. Sounds like it will need someone with Akka.NET knowledge to weigh in :-)

Comment: Yeah sorry for the confusion, I clarified the question a bit.